django bulk update with batch in multiple transactions
I've a certain code that updates bulk rows:
from simple_history.utils import bulk_update_with_history
from django.utils.timezone import now

bulk_update_list = []
for chart in updated_chart_records:
    chart.coder_assignment_sequence = count
    chart.queue_id = work_queue_pk
    chart.level_id = role_id
updated_num = bulk_update_with_history(bulk_update_list, Chart, ["coder_assignment_sequence", "l1_auditor_assignment_sequence", "l2_auditor_assignment_sequence", "l3_auditor_assignment_sequence","queue_id", "level_id", "comments", "reason_id"],
                                                           batch_size=10000, default_change_reason="work_queue")

Now data here can be very huge and sometimes thousands of rows to update.
This caused the database in lock:relation state for about 2-3 minutes.
On dissecting the bulk_update_with_history method which belonged to a simple-history package, the doc string states that:
def bulk_update_with_history(
    objs,
    model,
    fields,
    batch_size=None,
    default_user=None,
    default_change_reason=None,
    default_date=None,
    manager=None,
):
    """
    Bulk update the objects specified by objs while also bulk creating
    their history (all in one transaction).
    :param objs: List of objs of type model to be updated
    :param model: Model class that should be updated
    :param fields: The fields that are updated
    :param batch_size: Number of objects that should be updated in each batch

So the theory is that this particular function wraps all batch updates in a single transaction which is what caused the db to lock state.
I want to know how batch_size works in bulk_update. Django doc states that:
The batch_size parameter controls how many objects are saved in a single query. The default is to update all objects in one batch.

Also one suggestion was that to chunk list of records to be updated and call bulk_update_with_history for each chunk. This will ensure a separate transaction for each chunk and thus relieve the lock.
Any suggestions or idea on this please?

Is the .question for all items obj.question = 'Duplicate Questions'? Because then this can be boosted effectively. If it is different for each item, then it is a different story.

@willeM_VanOnsem I've updated the post. There are bunch of fields to update.
